# Python: Compare different keys in the same dictionary and sum it's values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the list which represents an hierarchical view of a chart of accounts.

```
chart_list = [{'id': 3, 'parent_id': 2, 'code': '1', 'name': 'MEIOS FIXOS E INVESTIMENTOS', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 4, 'parent_id': 3, 'code': '11', 'name': 'IMOBILIZACOES CORPOREAS', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 5, 'parent_id': 4, 'code': '111', 'name': 'Terrenos e recursos naturais', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 9, 'parent_id': 5, 'code': '1114', 'name': 'Terrenos com edifícios', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 13, 'parent_id': 4, 'code': '112', 'name': 'Edifícios e outras construções', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 14, 'parent_id': 13, 'code': '1121', 'name': 'Edifícios', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 21, 'parent_id': 4, 'code': '113', 'name': 'Equipamento básico', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 25, 'parent_id': 4, 'code': '114', 'name': 'Equipamentos de carga e transporte', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
...]
```

I this list I have the so called movement accounts and the organizational accounts.
The debits and credits are recorded in the transaction/movement accounts and these totals are reflected in each organization account where the transaction account belongs to.

The list structure is something like:

code/name

**0 - CHART OF ACCOUNTS**

**1 - SUB-ACCOUNT LEVEL 1**

**11 - SUB-ACCOUNT LEVEL 2**

111 - Normal move account 111

112 - Normal move account 112

**113 - Sub-account Level 3**

1131 - Normal account 1131

1132 - Normal account 1132

1134 - Normal account 1134

...

**2 - SUB-ACCOUNT LEVEL 1**

**21 - SUB-ACCOUNT LEVEL 2**

**211 - Sub-account level 3**

2111 - Normal account 2111

...

In the schema above, the debits/credits are recorded only in the "Normal accounts" and the sum of each account is passed to the parent account where the movement account belongs to (in bold).

For instance:
Debits/Credits recorded in the account 1134, 1132 and 1131 are added to the amount already in the parent account 113 and the amount in this 113 is added to the amount in 11 and later to the account 1.

In the list, I have the account id, and the account parent_id.
I need to loop through the list and look for parent_id of each account, and add the amount debit/credit to that parent account, which is represented by the id of that account.

So, on every account I have a parent_id which represents the id of the account I need and basically need to compare if id = parent_id, add the debit/credit on that id, and so on.

For instance...

```
...{'id': 4, 'parent_id': 3, 'code': '11', 'name': 'IMOBILIZACOES CORPOREAS', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 5, 'parent_id': 4, 'code': '111', 'name': 'Terrenos e recursos naturais', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, ...
```

The account code 111, has a parent_id = 4, which is the id of the account code 11 (id = 4).

I have tried to create a new list and add new elements if they do not exist and sum debits/credits if they exist.

Problem is I get lost because I need to compare diferent keys in the dictionary.

I have tried something like:

```
temp_result = {}
for each in res:
    key = (each['parent_id'] == each['id'])
    if key not in temp_result:
        #create a new value
        temp_result[key] = dict(id=None, parent_id=None, code=None, name=None, debit=0, credit=0)
        temp_result[key]['id'] = each['id']
        temp_result[key]['parent_id'] = each['parent_id']
        temp_result[key]['code'] = each['code']
        temp_result[key]['name'] = each['name']
        temp_result[key]['debit'] += each['debit']
        temp_result[key]['credit'] += each['credit']
    else:
        #update existing value
        temp_result[key]['debit'] += each['debit']
        temp_result[key]['credit'] += each['credit']
```

Comment: Why not use Pandas which would simplify such requirements.  Your existing List of Dictionaries will convert without problem into a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: @user19077881, thank you for your reply. I simple never used pandas before. Can you help achieve that using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how Pandas could be used on your data:

```
import pandas as pd

chart_list = [{'id': 3, 'parent_id': 2, 'code': '1', 'name': 'MEIOS FIXOS E INVESTIMENTOS', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 4, 'parent_id': 3, 'code': '11', 'name': 'IMOBILIZACOES CORPOREAS', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 5, 'parent_id': 4, 'code': '111', 'name': 'Terrenos e recursos naturais', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 9, 'parent_id': 5, 'code': '1114', 'name': 'Terrenos com edifícios', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 13, 'parent_id': 4, 'code': '112', 'name': 'Edifícios e outras construções', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 14, 'parent_id': 13, 'code': '1121', 'name': 'Edifícios', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 21, 'parent_id': 4, 'code': '113', 'name': 'Equipamento básico', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
{'id': 25, 'parent_id': 4, 'code': '114', 'name': 'Equipamentos de carga e transporte', 'debit': 0, 'credit': 0}, 
]

df = pd.DataFrame(chart_list).sort_values(by = 'parent_id')
print(df)
```

the code below is merely a simple example to show how the various values can be used (it sums the debit and the credit values for each parent_id). Other requirements could similarly be coded.

```
df2 = df.groupby('parent_id')[['debit', 'credit']].sum()
print(df2)
```

gives:

```
   id  parent_id  code                                name  debit  credit
0   3          2     1         MEIOS FIXOS E INVESTIMENTOS      0       0
1   4          3    11             IMOBILIZACOES CORPOREAS      0       0
2   5          4   111        Terrenos e recursos naturais      0       0
4  13          4   112      Edifícios e outras construções      0       0
6  21          4   113                  Equipamento básico      0       0
7  25          4   114  Equipamentos de carga e transporte      0       0
3   9          5  1114              Terrenos com edifícios      0       0
5  14         13  1121                           Edifícios      0       0
           
           debit  credit
parent_id               
2              0       0
3              0       0
4              0       0
5              0       0
13             0       0
```

Comment: Hello @user19077881. Thank you very much for your help. It is exactly what I need. I will deep in pandas because your code achieved exactly what I need.

Comment: You will find Pandas can do almost anything with tabular data. Some great videos on youtube, good books and lots of help on SO.